# Lambda function raising problems while merging data-frames

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, valueerror

```
for column in all_data[categorical_cols]:
    all_data[column].fillna(lambda x: x.fillna(x.value_counts().index[0]), inplace=True)


dummies_cols_created = pd.get_dummies(all_data[categorical_cols])


all_data = pd.merge(all_data[numeric_cols], all_data[dummies_cols_created], how='outer')
```

Here below I am pasting the error message.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-116-6a8a533bba3e> in <module>
----> 1 all_data = pd.merge(all_data[numeric_cols], all_data[dummies_cols_created], how='outer')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2887         # Do we have a (boolean) DataFrame?
   2888         if isinstance(key, DataFrame):
-> 2889             return self.where(key)
   2890 
   2891         # Do we have a (boolean) 1d indexer?

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in where(self, cond, other, inplace, axis, level, errors, try_cast)
   9003         other = com.apply_if_callable(other, self)
   9004         return self._where(
-> 9005             cond, other, inplace, axis, level, errors=errors, try_cast=try_cast
   9006         )
   9007 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _where(self, cond, other, inplace, axis, level, errors, try_cast)
   8764                 for dt in cond.dtypes:
   8765                     if not is_bool_dtype(dt):
-> 8766                         raise ValueError(msg.format(dtype=dt))
   8767         else:
   8768             # GH#21947 we have an empty DataFrame/Series, could be object-dtype

ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not int64
```

Comment: What `all_data[dummies_cols_created]` supposed to do? Did you mean `pd.merge(all_data[numeric_cols], dummies_cols_created, how='outer')` instead?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I would like to merge the numerical columns with the dummies ones.

Comment: Although, you probably would be better of with `all_data = pd.get_dummies(all_data, columns=categorical_cols)` in the first place (IIUC)